# Please advise if the algorithm written for deleting element from array is fine or not?

Tags: java, arrays

Below functions takes array and element to be deleted from array and return a new array. So I would like suggestion if this can be optimized some how or I am doing good in this.

```
public static int[] sbSample(int a[],int i){

    int size=0;
    int b[]=new int[a.length];
    for(int k=0;k<a.length;k++){
        if(!(a[k]==i)){

            b[size]=a[k];
            size++;
        }
    }
    for(int k=0;k<size;k++){
        System.out.println(b[k]);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Your question is better suited for the codereview webiste. See [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It would be useful if you included comments in your code snippet, that way readers would have a better understanding of your logic

Comment: it seems OK. if you want to keep int[], it ok. You could also just translate any data after the data you delete: you could win a little time.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `b.length == a.length` always, even if items are deleted.  If items are deleted, then b will have 0's at the end.  If you don't want that, then you should return b trimmed without the 0's at the end like:

```
return Arrays.copyOf(b, size);
```

Alternately, you could make b an ArrayList which can grow dynamically.